# Best practice to deploy -> development cycle when there are two lambda in cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have two lambda in cdk file.

With this source code `cdk deploy` do the first deployment, and after that,

Everytime do `cdk deploy` the new two lambda code are deployed.

However is it possible to deploy only one lambda?

What is the best practice for this case?

```
   const msgLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "firstLambda", {
      functionName: `sg-mg-lm`,
      code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
        "first",
        {
          "file": "Dockerfile.first"
        }
      ),
      environment:{
      }
    });
    const wkLambda = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "secondLambda", {
      functionName: `sg-wk-lm`,
      code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(
        "second",
        {
          "file": "Dockerfile.second"
        }
      ),
      environment:{
      }
    });
```

Comment: if the two lambdas aren't part of the same context, you should consider having two separate cdk stacks. That's the only thing that comes to mind to me on a use case like this.

Comment: I understood the cdk separate system.thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cdk deploy` operates at the stack level, not at the resource level. If the two lambda functions have their own lifecycle, then you should have one stack for each.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html):

> Many CDK Toolkit commands (for example, cdk deploy) work on stacks
> defined in your app. If your app contains only one stack, the CDK
> Toolkit assumes you mean that one if you don't specify a stack
> explicitly

with two stacks, let's say `Stack1` and `Stack2`, you can then choose which one to deploy with:

```
$ cdk deploy Stack1
```

or

```
$ cdk deploy Stack2
```

and even both at the same time:

```
$ cdk deploy Stack1 Stack2
```

Comment: Thank you very much I decided to use separate cdk. It works.